# How do I pass a variable to a function object?

Tags: c++, functor

In the examlpe below I need to define a function to compare my objects using certain rules in getHappiness(Animal*) method. The method cannot be static and rather complicated. I need a pointer in the comparison definition to call getHappiness method.

So my question is: how do I pass a pointer to this method, it gets called automatically when I insert an element into the map. And also it doesn't seem that I can instantiate Compare structure and pass the pointer to the constructor.

Am I doing anything wrong? Maybe there is an alternative way to how I define a comparison function?

```
struct Compare {bool operator()(Animal* const, Animal* const) const;}; 

bool
Compare::operator()(Animal* const a1, Animal* const a2) const {

  Zoo* zoo; // somehow I need to get access to the Zoo instance here

  if (zoo->getHappiness(a1) > zoo->getHappiness(a2)) return true;
  return false;
}

Class Zoo(){
  std::multimap<Animal*, Man*, Compare> map;

  int getHappiness(Animal*); // cannot be static

}

int main(){
...
  Zoo zoo;
  zoo.map.insert(...);
...
}
```

Comment: You could make it a template parameter to your `Compare` functor. I don't think it makes sense to being able to provide a runtime value to a custom Compare on a `std::multimap` anyway.

Comment: return happiness from animal not from zoo, should make your code much simpler.

Comment: @billz: I knew, but it needs so many things from main (in the real code), so would end up needing to pass much more values to animal insted. Might consider this again if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a design issue in your code. `Happiness` should be an attribute which belong to an `animal` not a `zoo`. So implement `getHappiness()` on `animal` makes your code much simpler:

```
struct Compare 
{
    bool operator()(Animal& const, Animal& const) const;
}; 

bool Compare::operator()(Animal& const a1, Animal& const a2) const 
{
    return a1.getHappiness() < a2.getHappiness();
}

Class Zoo(){
  std::multimap<Animal, Man, Compare> map;

}
```

Also, if not necessary, don't use pointer. If you can't avoid pointer, use smart pointer in STL container.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I have other options, but it would make even more  issues as I mentioned to your comment. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: write small class, simple functions, will save your life :)